# Как сымитировать нажатие нескольких клавиш на клавиатуре, включая специальные на Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Установил себе модуль `win32com.client`
В нём можно сделать имитацию нажатия клавиш (А ля `Ctrl + C`):

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.SendKeys('^a^x')
```

Однако в процессе появилась одна очень странная особенность: все эти имитация нажатия запускаются в фоновом потоке. В моём случае это недопустимо. Каким образом сделать так, чтобы вся программа ждала, пока сымитируется нажатие? Пробовал `threading` - получилось, однако программа теперь вместо 0.1с. работает 3с, что недопустимо.

Comment: А зачем вам имитировать нажатия клавиш?

Comment: @AndrioSkur вообще, программа должна копировать текст из любого текстового поля (будь то поле ввода комментария на Stackoverflow или поле ввода сообщений в Telegram'е), производить кое-какие операции над этой строкой и вставлять обратно. Решил для этой цели использовать имитацию нажатия клавиш Ctrl + A, Ctrl + X и Ctrl + V. А строку получаю из буфера обмена (использую pyperclip)

Comment: 1. Вы пробывали использывать multiprocessing вместо threading?(просто использвание multiprocessing создает потоки которые видит система, а не только питон) 2. Покажите свой вариант с threading

Comment: @AndrioSkur, модуль [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) порождает процессы, а не потоки. Потоки, порождаемые [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) - вполне нормальные с точки зрения ОС (можете запустить `top` или любой другой диспетчер и убедиться), система их "видит" вполне нормально - каждому потоку, по крайней мере в CPython, соответствует поток ОС. Более того, новые потоки порождаются не каким-то волшебством, а системными библиотеками, например, [pthreads](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

Comment: @m9_psy @AndrioSkur но вопрос всё ещё остаётся открытым: каким образом заставить программу ждать, пока выполнится имитация без использование `threading`? К сожалению, `multiprocessing` не помог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не принципиально использование модуля `win32com.client`, можно воспользоваться более удобным `pywinauto` (он ждёт отправки клавиш в приложение):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from datetime import datetime

# Запускаем блокнот
app = Application().start("notepad")

# Можно посылать спецсимволы
# app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("^a^v")
# app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("{VK_F5}")

# Вставим текущее время для проверки 
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))

print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

[Документация по эмуляции клавиатурных нажатий](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html)

Тестировалось на Python 3.6 со свежим `pywinauto`, Windows 7 64-bit